# $a_n X \to 0$ in distribution implies $a_n \to 0$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a random variable with $0 < \mathbb{E}X^2 < \infty$ and $\{a_n\}$ a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Is the following implication true?

$$a_n X \stackrel{d}{\to} 0 \implies a_n \to 0$$

Here  $0$ is the $0$-variable on our probability space. I guess it is true, but I can't prove it.

Working with characteristic functions, we have

$$\phi_X(a_nt)=\phi_{a_n X}(t) \to 1$$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$

In particular, $\phi_X(a_n) \to 1$. This doesn't seem to help.

EDIT:

Via Portmanteau, I was able to show that $a_n X\stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\to 0$ so we have a subsequence $a_{k_n} X \to 0$ a.s. and then taking a point where $X \neq 0$, we see that $a_{k_n} \to 0$; thus it is true that some subsequence must converge to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\min \{|x|,1\}$ is  a bounded  continuous function. So $Ef(a_nX) \to 0$. Suppose, if possible, $a_n$ does not tend to $0$. Then there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ and $r>0$ such that $|a_{n_k}| >r$ for all $k$. This gives $Ef(r|X|)=0$. This implies that $X=0$ almost surely contradicting the hypothesis that $EX^{2} >0$.

Comment: Why do we have $\mathbb{E} e^{-|a_n X|} \to 0$ instead of $\mathbb{E} e^{-|a_n X|} \to \mathbb{E} e^{0} =1$?

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity: for the "This gives" sentence, you also need (implicitly use) the fact that your $f$ is monotone, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. @ClementC.

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy. May I ask how you came up with the answer?